# Monitoring a matrix with changeable elements as Manipulate in plotting

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

If we remember, *Mathematica* has an ability to show a *Psudo-window* of plots for monitoring the effects of some changeable parameters in the functions. For example

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[r x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {r, 1, 5}]
```

If we have a matrix with a changeable parameter such as below

```
m = {{2j, j, -j, 0}, {2, j, -j, -2}, {2, 3, j, -j}, {0, j, -j, 2}};
 Do[ Print[m//MatrixForm],{j,0,100}]
```

I want to see the matrix effected by changeable `j`. If we use of Print, we must have a large series below code from 100 matrix which are 4*4. If matrix be larger, for example 20*20, the space consumed will be more huge for printing any matrix and thus for full of them.

Is there any way in *Mathematica* to monitoring the matrix just in one window and we can see the change of matrix's elements with a selectable speed (as we can use in `Manipulate`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `j` as the function argument for the matrix.

```
mat[j_] := {{2 j, j, -j, 0}, {2, j, -j, -2}, {2, 3, j, -j}, {0, j, -j,
 2}};
```

Then `Manipulate` works

```
Manipulate[
mat[j] // MatrixForm, {j, 0, 10, ControlType -> Animator, 
AnimationRate -> 1, RefreshRate -> 10}]
```

Comment: Wonderful, Excellent